# finding the maximum of a function using jax

Tags: python, gradient-descent, jax

I have a function which I would like to find its maximum by optimizing two of its variables using Jax.

The current code that I have currently, which does not work, reads

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax 
import scipy
import numpy as np

def temp_func(x,y,z):
    tmp = x + jnp.dot( jnp.power(y,3), jnp.tanh(z) )
    return -tmp
def obj_func(xy, z):
    x,y = xy[:2], xy[2:].reshape(2,2)
    return jnp.sum(temp_func(jnp.array(x),jnp.array(y),z))

grad_tmp = jax.grad(obj_func, argnums=0) # x,y

xy = jnp.concatenate([np.random.rand(2), np.random.rand(2*2) ])
z= jnp.array( np.random.rand(2,2) )
print(obj_func(xy,z))

result = scipy.optimize.minimize(obj_func,
                                 xy,
                                 args=(z,),
                                 method='L-BFGS-B',
                                 jac=grad_tmp
                                )
```

With this code, I get the error `ValueError: failed in converting 7th argument` g' of _lbfgsb.setulb to C/Fortran array`
Do you have any suggestions to resolve the issue?

Comment: I think you probably want to compute the grad of `obj_func` and not `temp_func`. So is the line `grad_tmp = jax.grad(temp_func, argnums=(0, 1)` correct?

Comment: indeed, it should be obj_func

Comment: The provided code doesn't raise an error for me: scipy '1.11.4', jax '0.4.23', numpy '1.26.2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might think about using the `jax` version of `scipy.optimize.minimize`, which will automatically compute and use the derivative:

```py
import jax.scipy.optimize
result = jax.scipy.optimize.minimize(obj_func, xy, args=(z,), method='BFGS')
```

That said, the results in either case are not going to be very meaningful, because your objective function is linearly decreasing in `x` and `y`, so it will be minimized when *x, y → ∞*